# Who is transferFrom function sending tokens from?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I'm new to Solidity and see:

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value)
    onlyOwner
    returns (bool)
{
  return super.transferFrom(from, to, value);
}
```

I mean is "from" here the contract address? Or can this be called by the owner to transfer from some address (given password) to any other address? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic flow for ERC-20.  Assume Alice, Bob, Charlie.

1. Bob calls `approve(Alice, 10)`.
2. Now Alice can call `transferFrom(Bob, Charlie, 10)`.

Without Bob's approval, Alice's call to `transferFrom` will error out: she can't send Bob's tokens without his approval.

If Alice wanted to send to Charlie, she would instead call `transfer(Charlie, 10)` but that would send Alice's tokens.

`from` and `to` are any address (it can be a contract, but doesn't have to be).

Comment: More clear now, but does this need onlyOwner modifier? Shouldn't this be only on "approve" function, assuming Bob is the owner?

Comment: Oh wait, so it doesn't matter as approve is always the msg.sender? Like: anyone who calls it gives permission of 3rd party to take some tokens from said sender? So onlyowner here is useless I guess.

Comment: Yes, `approve` typically always uses msg.sender.  Yes, tokens usually don't have onlyOwner.